# C# shoot towards mobile touch

Tags: c#, android, mobile, unity-game-engine, touch

Im currently working on one game,where user taps on screen(enemies), then a bullet should travel from camera to the touched location to kill the enemy. Enemies located at a distance 10units from camera(gun).

Suppose user touched at (x,y) = 5,5 then bullet should travel to 5,5,0 from camera location 0,0,-10.

I created a spawnPoint and attached to camera and also attached the shooter script to spawnPoint. Rigidbody projectile is a bullet prefab.

Please help me out of this.

Comment: I am not clear on what exactly your issue is. Are you asking us to provide you with physics code? Or is something not working as expected?

Comment: You need to be more specific on what's your doubt, as you described it's very hard to understand where you are getting lost.

Comment: how to achieve this is my question

Comment: how can i get the coordinates of touch input?

Answer (score 0):

```
float distance = 10f;

void Update()
{
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

    Shoot(ray.GetPoint(distance));
}

public void Shoot(float point)
{
    // shoot from camera location to point here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below approach worked perfectly for touch based input.

Vector3 fingerPos;

```
void Update () 
{
    if(Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)

    {
        fingerPos =  Input.GetTouch(0).position;        
        Vector3 pos = fingerPos;
        pos.z = 5;
        Vector3 realWorldPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(pos);
        transform.position = realWorldPos;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting the real world position of touch input using above code. But how to shoot a bullet from camera location(0,0,-10) to real world position(x, x, 5) when user touched the screen.